# JQuery .on event and other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since .live() is deprecated, I started to use .on().

I have the following code:

```
$('.myClass').on("click", function(event)
{
    var args = '......';

     SendAjax(args);
});
```

The SendAjax function does this:

```
SendAjax(args)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: webPageName,
        data: queryParams+'&'+unique,
        success: function(result)
        {
            MyReturnFunction(result);
        }
    });
}
```

The ajax will return to this function:

```
MyReturnFunction(response)
{
      $('.myClass').html(response);
}
```

But after this MyReturnFunction(), the events on .myClass doesn't work anymore. How do I fix this with .on() or .bind()?

Comment: whether on function is under document ready ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.on()` function can take an extra argument:

```
$('body').on('click', '.myClass', function() { ... });
```

That's what `.live()` did for you, but it was a backwards API design. Now you have to decide where to put the delegated handler. The body element is a good default, but it can be any parent. Sometimes when you're handling clicks on things in tables it's nice to do the binding at the `<table>` element (though the body works fine then too).

So basically the rule is that when you used to write:

```
$('something').live('event-name', function() { ... })
```

you write:

```
$('container-selector').on('event-name', 'something', function() { ... })
```

The "container-selector" says where you want the *real* event handler placed — the one that checks to see whether the target of a bubbled event matches the given "something" selector. As before, you can pass a list of event names (separated by spaces) instead of just one. There's also a variant that lets you pass an object mapping event names to functions.

Comment: @chris no, not really.  The event bubbling happens inside the browser, and if you think about it even in a complicated page there aren't that many levels of nesting. Besides, that's how `.live()` worked anyway - it **always** used `<body>`  (*edit* I mean "inside the browser's internal code, not in JavaScript")